# Handling specific Python error within Bash call?

Tags: python, bash

I am using the `line_profiler`, which allows you to drop `@profile` decorators anywhere in a python codebase and returns line output.

However, if you try to execute python code that contains one such `@profile` decorator without loading this `line_profiler` module, the code will fail with a NameError, for such a decorator is defined and injected by this external library.

I'd like a bash command that attempts to run my python script with vanilla python. Then, if and only if the error consists of `NameError`, I want to give it a second try. This is what I have got so far:

```
python -u $file || python -m kernprof -l -v --outfile=/dev/null $file"
```

The problem is of course that if my python code has ANY errors at all, be it `ValueError` or `IndentationError` or anything, it tries the profiler. I want to ONLY run the profiler if the error contains a string `NameError: name 'profile' is not defined` is found within `stderr`.

Comment: Can't this be done with `grep`?

Comment: Maybe? I'm looking into `grep`ing `stderr`, but I can't quite get things working.

Comment: [This guy](http://zcentric.com/2013/05/06/grep-only-stderr-from-a-command/) does this: `cmd 2> >(grep -v "WARNING" >&2)` which seems along the right lines. I need another mini-program that either "fails" or "succeeds" based on `stderr` I guess?

Comment: why not just use subprocess and run it from python

Comment: feels like I should be able to do it in bash. it's going into a sublime build system, I'd prefer not to depend on another floating associated .py file

Comment: [*What you cannot do is capture stdout in one variable, and stderr in another, using only FD redirections. You must use a temporary file (or a named pipe) to achieve that one.*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002)

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't be better to monkey patch profile when no line_profiles is present ?

Something like

```
try:
    import line_profiles
except:
    import warnings
    warnings.warn("Profile disabled")

    def profile(fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            return fn(*args, **kw)
        return wrapper
```

This way your code runs in either case without complicating matters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a usable Bash solution that preserves `stdout` and `stderr` as separate streams (with the caveat that `stderr` appears after `stdout`) and only checks `stderr` for the error message (which probably is overkill though).

It goes the easy route and simply saves the `stderr` output to a file. It also handles script names that contain spaces (by properly quoting variable expansions where needed) and/or start with `-` (by passing `--` before the filename to switch off flag processing) as it's an OCD pet peeve of mine.

On success or if there is an error that is not the expected error, the `stderr` of the first `python` command is shown. Otherwise (for the expected error), it is hidden.

Usage is  `$ ./check <script>`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    echo "Expected one argument: the script" >&2
    exit 1
fi

script=$1

if [[ ! -e $script ]]; then
    echo "'$script' does not exist or is not a regular file" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if ! python -- "$script" 2>saved_stderr &&
   grep -q "NameError: name 'profile' is not defined" saved_stderr; then

    # Try again with the kernprof module.
    python -m kernprof -l -v --outfile=/dev/null -- "$script"

else
    # Either success or an unexpected error. Show stderr.
    cat saved_stderr >&2
fi

rm saved_stderr
```

- To check if the return status of a command is zero (i.e., success), it suffices to do

  ```
  if <cmd>; then <if successful>; fi`
  ```

  `!` negates the exit status, so `if ! <cmd> ...` can be used to check for failure. `!` only applies to the `python` command above, not all of `python ... && grep ...`.
- `>&2` redirects `stdout` to `stderr`. (It's the same as `1>&2` but saves a single character, which is a bit silly, but I included for illustrative purposes as it's a common idiom.)

Answer (score 1):

Creating a simple Python wrapper would seem a lot more straightforward, because inside Python, you have access to the things which go wrong.

Assuming your `$file` uses the common `__name__ == '__main__'` idiom something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

you can create a wrapper something like

```
import yourfile
try:
    file.main()
except NameError:
    import kernprof
    # hack hack, quickly constructed from looking at main() in kernprof.py
    prof = kernprof.ContextualProfile()
    execfile_ = execfile
    ns = locals()
    try:
        prof.runctx('execfile_(%r, globals())' % (yourfile,), ns, ns)
    finally:
        prof.print_stats()
```